# PresentViewController to a ViewController with a different NavigationController but on the same storyboard

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin, storyboard

I'm having trouble with a simple Xamarin Studio Storyboards concept.  See screenshots below for visuals and see the [downloadable source code here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2pxrmrmxo8so28/Storyboard.Manual_StackOverflow.zip?dl=0).

Let's say I have a NavigationController with MainViewController on it.  This is visible in my storyboard.  I want a button which, when pressed, brings up a new NavigationController with RedViewController.  I also want RedViewController on the same storyboard as the MainViewController.  In this project, I tried to do that but for some reason when I do a:

```
var myStoryboard = AppDelegate.Storyboard;
// Instatiating View Controller with Storyboard ID 'StuffViewController'
RedViewController = myStoryboard.InstantiateViewController ("RedViewController") as RedViewController;
RedViewController.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical;
this.PresentViewController(RedViewController, true, null);
```

the RedViewController doesn't have it's Navigation controller with it.  When presented RedViewController's Navigation Controller is null!  What am I doing wrong there?
[image]

Now when I created a NavigationController & BlueViewController in a totally seperate storyboard it works fine.  When I press the Blue Button it goes to the BlueViewController and correctly shows it's NavigationController.  Why is this one working but the other one not?  The only difference that I can see is that they are on separate Storyboards.
[image]

```
UIStoryboard storyBoard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("BlueStoryboard", null);
UIViewController controller = storyBoard.InstantiateInitialViewController () as UIViewController;
controller.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical;
this.PresentViewController (controller, true, null);
```

ViewController that can present a new NavigationController & ViewController ViewController called "Red" with a navigation bar

[image: Main Storyboard with additional Red NavigationController/ViewController]
[image: Blue Storyboard, that works as desired.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you instantiate your new view controller you need to instantiate the `UINavigationController`, not the `RedViewController`.

In the case of your 'blue' code you instantiate the `initialViewController` - which is the navigation controller that contains the Blue controller.

You want

```
RedViewNavigationController = myStoryboard.InstantiateViewController ("RedViewNavigationController") as UINavigationController;
```

where 'RedViewNavigationController' is the identifier for the navigation controller that the Red View Controller is embedded in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to present the red controller with its navigation controller, you should instantiate the navigation controller (which, in turn, will instantiate the red controller), and present it.